# Can we DELETE whole table in hive's latest version?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hivecontext

there is table "student" created in hive 0.14 version. i want to delete that table. can use DELETE command for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

DROP TABLE table_name_goes_here;